# Does HDD Speed matter on Unix after boot?

Tags: centos6

I am configuring a mysql / webserver (2X 3.4Ghz 6 core, 96GB RAM) and waiting for the SSD drives to get here and wondered if I would really notice any difference in performance having the OS on the SSD?

I realize the SSD would speed up boot time, but with 96GB RAM, I wasn't sure if it wouldn't just load the whole thing into memory and only check the physical disks occasionally to write log entries and such. I have 2 Dell Constellation 2 1TB 2.5" drives I was going to put into a RAID 1 or could also use a couple 146GB 15K SAS drives unless I should wait.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [should I install my OS on my ssd or hdd](http://superuser.com/questions/316570/should-i-install-my-operating-system-on-my-ssd-or-hdd), also not entirely relevant to serverfault.

Comment: I can see this as a duplicate as pointed out. But why is it not about `server, networking, or related infrastructure administration`?

Answer (score 5):

As you may expect, this depends on whatever other workload you'll have on the OS drives.  If it is just the OS, logging, yum caches, ...  Then it will not make a big difference.  The SSD will make some routine operations faster, such as Yum update.

If you are also going to place databases, sendmail mail queues, or anything else with high synchronous writing activity, on these same drives *and* will have a lot of write activity (database insert/update/delete or emails), then you may want to opt for the SSDs.

I hope this helps you make the best decision.